# Cannot find code for vm.onSelect(user) used for ng-click action

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to lift methodology from the following HTML code snippet. What results is a list of items that can be individually selected. However, I cannot find the function "onSelect()" defined anywhere in this working code's workspace. I need it for the ng-click to work properly. This is lifted from working code. Sorry for the stupid question, but I am a newbie.

I don't know if this is a built-in function, but it does not appear when I do a google search on it.

The relevant HTML is as follows:

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-click="vm.onSelect(user)"
       ng-init="vm.onSelect(user)"
       ng-class="{'info':vm.selected=user}"
       ng-repeat="user in vm.results.items | orderBy:vm.sort.column:vm.sort.descending| filter:vm.isMatch">
       <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
       <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
       <td><username dn="{{user.userName}}"></username></td>
   </tr>
<tbody>
```

Comment: Search for that function in all the javascript files that you have included in your html

Comment: If you are still facing some problem then upload your project to github and share the link if the code is not part of some commercial application that you are developing